# What is a compact way to save a float32array to disk on node.js?

Tags: arrays, node.js, serialization

JSON.stringify is obviously not space-efficient. What is the most elegant way to serialize and store a float32array using Node.js?

EDIT: People are closing the question for reasons such as being "opinion based" and "lack of an understanding of the problem". I seriously believe the first one was a missclick. For the second one, maybe this makes it more clear:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var len = 1000*1000*10;
var big_array = new Float32Array(len);
for (var i=0; i<len; ++i)
    big_array[i] = Math.random();

// OBVIOUSLY NOT SPACE EFFICIENT \/
fs.writeFileSync("big_array.json",JSON.stringify(big_array));
```

It is not space efficient because you are representing numbers as strings, so an 8 bytes float will be using as much as ~20 utf8 chars, which is a waste. The question is: how to store the array in a space-efficient manner?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what is "elegant" when it comes to serialization?

Comment: Understand elegant as the standard you're supposed to make this, the same way as JSON.stringify is the intended way to serialize arbitrary data.

Comment: Regarding your edit about close reasons: when you ask for "elegance", that translates to opinion. Have you tried saving the `buffer` property of the array? It's just bytes.

Comment: Perhaps use [`buf.writeFloat*`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writefloatle_value_offset_noassert) and save the buffer to disk?

Comment: I'm also very interested on this. I need this to store from node and retrieve from a browser a Float32Array. I can't rely on JSON because if the array is too big, like 1M of float values it easily reach a lot of MB (for example I've just tried to serialize an array of 220k values and it's serialized to a JSON of 2.3MB)

Answer (score 14):

Finally I managed to write float32array to disk with nodejs and retrieve them on the browser, and I hope it will help you.

### Write Float32Array to binary file in NodeJS

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('data.dat');

    var data = new Float32Array([1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5]);

    //prepare the length of the buffer to 4 bytes per float
    var buffer = new Buffer(data.length*4);


    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        //write the float in Little-Endian and move the offset
        buffer.writeFloatLE(data[i], i*4);
    }

    wstream.write(buffer);
    wstream.end();
```

### Read the file and convert it to a Float32Array on a Browser

```
    var urlToFloatFile = 'data.dat';
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', urlToFloatFile, true);

    //specify the response type as arraybuffer
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    request.onload = function (msg) { 
        var yourFloatData = new Float32Array(this.response);
        console.log(yourFloatData);
    };
    request.send();
```

> Thanks to @ben_a_adams from WebGL Dev List GGroup https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webgl-dev-list/EbGUi_iSEx8 for the client side code

I've create a simple test to test roughly how much space a JSON serialization of a float array differs from a binary representation and the results are:

- 2.000.000 floating point values
- 7.8MB on a binary file
- 38.5MB on a JSON file
- 17.5 on a Gzipped JSON file

Comment: Reading file can also be improved using the `fetch` API: https://gist.github.com/jpweeks/9ccbfdfbcf69babf2e745c3ae0cc45d4

Answer (score 5):

Easy, clean way to do it:

```js
const float32Array = new Float32Array([.69,.420])
const buffer = Buffer.from(float32Array.buffer)
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, buffer)
const loadedBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath)
const newFloat32Array = new Float32Array(loadedBuffer.buffer)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a much simpler version possible

```
let fs = require('fs')
let data = [150, 180]
fs.writeFileSync('mydata', new Buffer(new Uint32Array(data).buffer))
fs.readFile('mydata', (err, buf) => {
    let restoredData = new Uint32Array(buf.buffer, buf.offset, buf.byteLength/4)
    console.log(data[1])
    console.log(restoredData[1])
});
```

Comment: This looks great

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use Meteor's EJSON:

http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson

https://npmjs.org/package/meteor-ejson

> EJSON is an extension of JSON to support more types. It supports all
>   JSON-safe types, as well as:
>
> - Date (JavaScript Date)
> - Binary (JavaScript Uint8Array or the result of    EJSON.newBinary)
> - User-defined types (see EJSON.addType. For example,    Meteor.Collection.ObjectID is implemented this way.)